# angular ui-router passing values to states from html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 2 routes that require a parameters. 
One is a parent of the other:

```
/a/:a_value/b/:b_value
```

The [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref) say to "Navigate to state, with params." do:

```
ui-sref='stateName({param: value, param: value})'
```

but when i try to do that it doesn't work:

```js
//in controller:
$scope.aValue = 1;
$scope.bValue = 2;

//in router config:
.state("a", {
  url: "/a/:a_value"
})
.state("a.b", {
  url: "/b/:b_value"
});
```

```html
this works correctly:

<a ng-href="/a/{{aValue}}/b/{{bValue}}">the angular way</a>

it outputs:
<a href="/a/1/b/2">the angular way</a>

this doesn't work correctly:
<a ui-sref="a.b({a_value: a_value, b_value: bValue })">the ui-router way?</a>

it outputs:
<a href="/a/b/">the ui-router way?</a>
```

Assuming everything else works properly in my application, shouldn't that work?

Comment: I've also tried stuff like ui-sref="a({a_value: aValue}).b({b_value: bValue})" but they don't work or throw an error.

Comment: As you can see I spent some time and effort on answering your question. Unfortunately this went without any reaction from you. Eventhough I do not expect accepts or votes, I do expect you to read my answer and give some feedback, just like you do when you ask things on SO. If only out of decency.

Comment: @skubski the next time you feel that feeling of 'i spent some time and effort and got no reaction' when answering a question to someone on the internet, rather than feeling upset that they didn't acknowledge you, first consider the possibility that they died. Totally possible and you'd never know about it. Next consider that they have their life to live- perhaps their grandpa just was diagnosed with stage (x) cancer/death and s/o isn't their main concern. After considering those two things, if you still feel upset, write an entitled rant. I'm alive. I appreciate your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it right in your third attempt. The following line of code should have worked. (Assuming all the rest is correct)

```
<li><a href ui-sref="a.b({a_value: 1, b_value: 2})">b</a></li>
```

The ui-router docs does however warn their users about a common [pitfall](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha). I'm not sure if you took this into account but it is definitely applicable in this given use case.

> ### Important $stateParams Gotcha
>
> In state controllers, the $stateParams object will only contain the
>   params that were registered with that state. So you will not see
>   params registered on other states, including ancestors.

```
$stateProvider.state('contacts.detail', {
   url: '/contacts/:contactId',   
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
   }
}).state('contacts.detail.subitem', {
   url: '/item/:itemId', 
   controller: function($stateParams){
      $stateParams.contactId //*** Watch Out! DOESN'T EXIST!! ***//
      $stateParams.itemId //*** Exists! ***//  
   }
})
```

Nevertheless, you could still pass an object with several properties into your state as long as it contains a matching parameter. I worked out the code you posted into a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u3fJcRISIfjixLTlME4O?p=preview).

```
  $stateProvider.state("a", {
    url: "/a/:a_value",
    templateUrl: 'a.html',
    controller: 'AController as a'
  });
  $stateProvider.state("a.b", {
    url: "/b/:b_value",
    templateUrl: 'b.html',
    controller: 'BController as b'
  });
```

Using the following navigation:

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href ui-sref="a({a_value: 3})">a</a></li>
      <li><a href ui-sref="a.b({a_value: 1, b_value: 2})">b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

You could replace the values of a_value and b_value with scope arguments as you see fit. Since b is a child of a, it will search for a nested ui-view inside its parents template, so make sure you supply one.

```
<h1>{{a.hello}}</h1>

{{a.$stateParams}}

<ui-view></ui-view>
```

You can find the complete example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/u3fJcRISIfjixLTlME4O?p=preview).